# facebook authentication working with angular ui router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, angular-ui-router, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to authenticate angular single page web application with angular facebook sdk that would work with angular ui router where the $stateProvider would check and remember user facebook status, would redirect to facebook login when user needs to authenticate to access the selected view ? How to save facebook status in angular ui controller and later check if the user status without calling facebook ?

Comment: where is your code? where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am stuck how to make angular ui router stateProvider recognize what is the state of a user without needing to get the status or call login from facebook when the user status has already done that already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, create app with the view and controller defined for the facebook.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/facebook");
  $stateProvider
    .state("facebook", {
      url: "/facebook",
      templateUrl: "facebook.html",
      controller: 'facebooktrl'

    });
});
```

You need to use the fbSDK as mentioned in the developers document and configure the redirect url too.

Here is a **[DEMO application](https://github.com/sajeetharan/FBAngularApp)**